# Supported API Levels for Android Health Connect

Tags: android, google-fit

I have a question about Health Connect.
The official Android documentation states the following
https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/develop/get-started

Health Connect SDK supports API Level 26 or higher.
Health Connect App supports API Level 28 or higher.
All health data is read/write data via Health Connect App.

What can a terminal with API Level 26 do in this situation?
If it can't read/write data without the Health Connect App,
What can a terminal with API Level 26, which is only supported by the Health Connect SDK, do?